# Remove specific variable from URI string

Tags: php

With `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, I get a URL that could be:

```
index.php
```

or

```
index.php?id=x&etc..
```

I'd like to do two things:

1. Find if there is a **?something** after `index.php` name with regular expression.
2. If there is in the url a specific var (**id=x**) and delete it from the url.

For example:

```
index.php?id=x       => index.php 
index.php?a=11&id=x  => index.php?a=11
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if there is a `?something` after `index.php`, you could use the built-in function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url), like so:

```
if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY)) {
    // ?something exists
}
```

To remove the `id`, you could use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str), get the query parameters, store them in an array, and unset the particular `id`.

And since you also want to re-create the URL after the particular element is deleted from the query part of the URL, then you could use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query).

Here's a function for that:

```
function removeQueryString($url, $toBeRemoved, $match) 
{
    // check if url has query part
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY)) {

        // parse_url and store the values
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        $scriptname = $parts['path'];
        $query_part = $parts['query'];

        // parse the query parameters from the url and store it in $arr
        $query = parse_str($query_part, $arr);

        // if id == x, unset it
        if (isset($arr[$toBeRemoved]) && $arr[$toBeRemoved] == $match) {
            unset($arr[$toBeRemoved]);

            // if there less than 1 query parameter, don't add '?'
            if (count($arr) < 1) {
                $query = $scriptname . http_build_query($arr);

            } else {
                $query = $scriptname . '?' . http_build_query($arr);  
            }
        } else {
            // no matches found, so return the url
            return $url;
        }
        return $query;
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
echo removeQueryString('index.php', 'id', 'x');
echo removeQueryString('index.php?a=11&id=x', 'id', 'x');
echo removeQueryString('index.php?a=11&id=x&qid=51', 'id', 'x');
echo removeQueryString('index.php?a=11&foo=bar&id=x', 'id', 'x');
```

Output:

```
index.php
index.php?a=11
index.php?a=11&qid=51
index.php?a=11&foo=bar
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/52484)

Comment: There is a problem. I set $toBeRemoved='id', $match='12'. If url is index.php?id=12&a=10 return index.php?a=10 but if it's not match example-> index.php?id=11&a=10 return blank.

Answer (score 1):

If it *must* be a regular expression :

```
$url='index.php?a=11&id=1234';
$pattern = '#\id=\d+#';
$url = preg_replace($pattern, '', $url);

echo $url;
```

output

> index.php?a=11&

There is a trailing `&`, but the above removes any id=xxxxxxxx

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I realized that it is better to use the method suggested by Amal Murali

Comment: @Paolo - I totally agree!